# Issues with Text Box display in Opera and Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, opera

i need your help with my textbox placeholder display, for Opera and Firefox.
 The letters do not display fully when i type into the box. This does not occur in Google Chrome.

It currently looks like this

**Image**

[image]

**CSS**

```
.Input_Text { 
border:    none !; 
outline:    none;    
font-size:  15px;
margin:   5px 5px 5px 0px;
width:    195px;
height:    5px;
color:      black;
opacity:     0.6;
padding:    10px 10px;   
border-radius:  5px;  
font-family:  lucida grande;
margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height is messing with the code. You can set it with the padding property.

Answer (score 0):

`height:    5px;`  -- this must be your culprit!!! ..

Try 15px/20px or more..

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the height

```
.Input_Text { 
    border:    none !; 
    outline:    none;    
    font-size:  15px;
    margin:   5px 5px 5px 0px;
    width:    195px;
    height:    10px;
    color:      black;
    opacity:     0.6;
    padding:    10px 10px;   
    border-radius:  5px;  
    font-family:  lucida grande;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bmtCv/3/)